# Can anyone help me about cost function in linear regression. As from the below plot we have input values and predicted value there is no Y value, help

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, cost-function

**Can anyone help out please? I don't understand this**

[image: Linear Regression]

Comment: I see three $Y$ values in $1$, $2$, and $3$. Plug those into the equation and calculate $J$.

Answer (score 0):

I’m going to solve a different problem so that you still have to do something on your own for your homework, but this should give you a template for solving your assignment.

$$
(X_1,Y_1)=(1,1)\\
(X_2,Y_2)=(3,5)
$$

If $h_{\theta}(x)=\theta_0+\theta_1x+\theta_2x^2$, let’s calculate the cost $J(\theta_0,\theta_1,\theta_2)=\sum_i \big(h(x^{(i)}-y^{(i)}
\big)^2$when $\theta_0=\theta_1=\theta_2=2$.

$$
J(2,2,2) = \bigg(\big(2+2(1)+2(1^2)\big)-1\bigg)^2
+
\bigg(\big(
2+2(3)+2(3^2)
\big)
-5\bigg)^2 \\
=
25+441\\=466
$$